# Error in dyn.load() : unable to load shared object

Tags: c, r

I have modified "randomForest" packages in R.

As you know, we can customize the randomForest package by modifing the C 
file.

First, i downloaded the randomForest crab file that include many c file. classTree.c, regrf.c, rf.c etc.

Second, I run the $ R CMD SHLIB rf.c in terminal on macOS. And then, i can get the "rf.so" file.

Third, I run the dyn.load("rf.so") in R. I have a following problem.

```
dyn.load("path/rf.so")
Error in dyn.load("path/rf.so") : 
  unable to load shared object 'path/rf.so':
  dlopen(path/rf.so, 6): Symbol not found: _Xtranslate
  Referenced from: path/rf.so
  Expected in: flat namespace
 in path/rf.so
```

how can i solve this problem?